# Rotation issue in 3D Model in OpenGl

Tags: android, opengl-es, rotation

I want to rotate the object z axis so I am using the below code but its not rotating at particular position its rotation just go back and appear come near. I think there is wrong with the values in `GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);`. Please help me to set the correct values of these So that rotation works well.

```
gl.glTranslatef(mOrigin.x, mOrigin.y, mOrigin.z);
gl.glRotatef(mRotate.x, 1f, 0f, 0f);
gl.glRotatef(mRotate.y, 0f, 1f, 0f);
gl.glRotatef(mRotate.z, 0f, 0f, 1f);


private class Renderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    public Renderer() {
        setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        setZOrderOnTop(true);
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
        mViewWidth = (float)w;
        mViewHeight = (float)h;
        gl.glViewport(0,0,w,h);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45, mViewWidth/mViewHeight, 0.1f, 100f);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glPushMatrix();

        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER); 

        GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

        //draw_model
        gl.glPushMatrix();

        if(mOrigin != null && mRotate != null) {
            gl.glTranslatef(mOrigin.x, mOrigin.y, mOrigin.z);
            gl.glRotatef(mRotate.x, 1f, 0f, 0f);
            gl.glRotatef(mRotate.y, 0f, 1f, 0f);
            gl.glRotatef(mRotate.z, 0f, 0f, 1f);
        }

        if(mModel != null) {
            mModel.draw(gl, mContext);
            if(!RendererView.textureFileName.equals(""))
                mModel.bindTextures(mContext, gl);
        }

        gl.glPopMatrix();
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        if(isPictureTake) {
            w = getWidth();
            h = getHeight();
            b = new int[w*(y+h)];
            bt = new int[w*h];

            IntBuffer ib = IntBuffer.wrap(b);
            ib.position(0);
            gl.glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ib);
            createBitmapFromGLSurface(mContext);
            isPictureTake = false;
        }
    }
}
```

ObjLoader.java

```
package com.amplimesh.models;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;

import com.amplimesh.renderer.RendererView;
import com.amplimesh.util.Point3;

/**
 * Object Loader and draw the texture and object.
 * @author Ajay
 */
public class ObjModel {

    /**
     * It fill the texture into the mesh
     * @param context
     * @param gl
     */
    public void bindTextures(Context context, GL10 gl) {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try {
            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("textures/"+RendererView.textureFileName);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            if(bitmap != null) {
                // generate one texture pointer
                gl.glGenTextures(1, mTextures, 0);
                // ...and bind it to our array
                gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures[0]);

                // create nearest filtered texture
                gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
                gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

                //Different possible texture parameters, e.g. GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
                //gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
                //gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);

                // Use Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap 
                GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
                // Clean up
                bitmap.recycle();
            }
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * It draw the object.
     * @param gl
     */
    public void draw(GL10 gl, Context mContext) {
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        for (Model model : mModels) {

            gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, model.v);
            if (model.vt != null && mTextures != null) {
                gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures[0]);
                gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, model.vt);
            }

            if (model.vn != null) {
                gl.glNormalPointer(GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, model.vn);
            }
            gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, model.v_size);
        }

        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    }

    /**
     * It Load the object from stream.
     * @param is
     * @param texture_name
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static ObjModel loadFromStream(InputStream is, String texture_name) throws IOException {
        ObjModel obj = ObjLoader.loadFromStream(is);
        return obj;
    }

    private Model mModels[];
    private int mTextures[] = new int[1];;

    /**
     * It read the the obj file.
     * @author Ajay
     */
    private static class ObjLoader {

        public static ObjModel loadFromStream(InputStream is) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            ObjModel obj = new ObjModel();
            ArrayList<Point3> v = new ArrayList<Point3>();
            ArrayList<Point3> vt = new ArrayList<Point3>();
            ArrayList<Point3> vn = new ArrayList<Point3>();
            ArrayList<Face> f = new ArrayList<Face>();

            ArrayList<Model> o = new ArrayList<Model>();

            boolean o_pending=false;

            while(reader.ready()) {
                String line = reader.readLine();
                if (line == null) 
                    break;

                StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(line);
                String cmd = tok.nextToken();

                if (cmd.equals("o")) {
                    if (o_pending) {
                        Model model = new Model();
                        model.fill(f, vt.size() > 0, vn.size() > 0);
                        o.add(model);
                    }
                    else {
                        o_pending=true;
                    }
                }
                else
                    if (cmd.equals("v")) {
                        v.add(read_point(tok));
                    }
                    else
                        if (cmd.equals("vn")) {
                            vn.add(read_point(tok));
                        }
                        else
                            if (cmd.equals("vt")) {
                                vt.add(read_point(tok));
                            }
                            else
                                if (cmd.equals("f")) {
                                    if (tok.countTokens() != 3)
                                        continue;

                                    Face face = new Face(3);
                                    while (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                        StringTokenizer face_tok = new StringTokenizer(tok.nextToken(), "/");

                                        int v_idx = -1;
                                        int vt_idx = -1;
                                        int vn_idx = -1;
                                        v_idx = Integer.parseInt(face_tok.nextToken());
                                        if (face_tok.hasMoreTokens()) vt_idx = Integer.parseInt(face_tok.nextToken());
                                        if (face_tok.hasMoreTokens()) vn_idx = Integer.parseInt(face_tok.nextToken());

                                        //Log.v("objmodel", "face: "+v_idx+"/"+vt_idx+"/"+vn_idx);

                                        face.addVertex(
                                                v.get(v_idx-1),
                                                vt_idx == -1 ? null : vt.get(vt_idx-1),
                                                        vn_idx == -1 ? null : vn.get(vn_idx-1)
                                                );
                                    }
                                    f.add(face);
                                }
            }

            if (o_pending) {
                Model model = new Model();
                model.fill(f, vt.size() > 0, vn.size() > 0);
                o.add(model);
            }

            obj.mModels = new Model[o.size()];
            o.toArray(obj.mModels);
            return obj;
        }

        private static Point3 read_point(StringTokenizer tok) {
            Point3 ret = new Point3();
            if (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
                ret.x = Float.parseFloat(tok.nextToken());
                if (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    ret.y = Float.parseFloat(tok.nextToken());
                    if (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
                        ret.z = Float.parseFloat(tok.nextToken());
                    }
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }

    }

    private static class Face {
        Point3 v[];
        Point3 vt[];
        Point3 vn[];
        int size;
        int count;

        public Face(int size) {
            this.size = size;
            this.count = 0;
            this.v = new Point3[size];
            this.vt = new Point3[size];
            this.vn = new Point3[size];
        }

        public boolean addVertex(Point3 v, Point3 vt, Point3 vn) {
            if (count >= size)
                return false;
            this.v[count] = v;
            this.vt[count] = vt;
            this.vn[count] = vn;
            count++;
            return true;
        }

        public void pushOnto(FloatBuffer v_buffer, FloatBuffer vt_buffer, FloatBuffer vn_buffer) {
            int i;
            for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
                v_buffer.put(v[i].x); v_buffer.put(v[i].y); v_buffer.put(v[i].z);

                if (vt_buffer != null && vt[i] != null) {
                    vt_buffer.put(vt[i].x); vt_buffer.put(vt[i].y);
                }

                if (vn_buffer != null && vn[i] != null) {
                    vn_buffer.put(vn[i].x); vn_buffer.put(vn[i].y); vn_buffer.put(vn[i].z);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * It hold the vertex buffer, vertex normal and texture.
     * @author Ajay
     */
    private static class Model {
        public FloatBuffer v;
        public FloatBuffer vt;
        public FloatBuffer vn;
        public int v_size;

        public void fill(ArrayList<Face> faces, boolean has_tex, boolean has_normals) {
            int f_len = faces.size();

            this.v_size = f_len * 3;

            ByteBuffer tBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(this.v_size*3 * 4);
            tBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            this.v = tBuf.asFloatBuffer();

            if (has_tex) {
                ByteBuffer vtBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(this.v_size*3 * 4);
                vtBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
                this.vt = vtBuf.asFloatBuffer();
            }

            if (has_normals) {
                ByteBuffer vnBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(this.v_size*3 * 4);
                vnBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
                this.vn = vnBuf.asFloatBuffer();
            }

            int i;
            for (i=0; i < f_len; i++) {
                Face face = faces.get(i);
                face.pushOnto(this.v, this.vt, this.vn);
            }

            this.v.rewind();
            if (this.vt != null)
                this.vt.rewind();
            if (this.vn != null)
                this.vn.rewind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ordinarily you want to rotate around an object's center. If you rotate before translating an object this helps a lot. If you already have a camera that's not at (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) you should: Translate (-CamerPos) , Rotate ..., Translate (CameraPos + mOrigin)

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Thanks for your reply. I did not get your last `If you already have a camera that's not at (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) you should: Translate (-CamerPos) , Rotate ..., Translate (CameraPos + mOrigin)`. Please can you help me by writing some small piece of code

Answer (score 0):

To rotate an object at a specific position around an axis, you first need to translate the object's center to the origin. In your example, you have an object at (mOrigin) which *may* be relative to another translation (your camera's position).

Instead of translating your object to its final position and then rotating, you need to translate it to (0,0,0), rotate and then translate to the final position.

In the simplest case this would be:

```
gl.glRotatef    (mRotate.x, 1f, 0f, 0f);
gl.glRotatef    (mRotate.y, 0f, 1f, 0f);
gl.glRotatef    (mRotate.z, 0f, 0f, 1f);
gl.glTranslatef (mOrigin.x, mOrigin.y, mOrigin.z);
```

In the more complicated case, where your object is relative to the camera, you would have to do something like this:

```
gl.glTranslatef (-Camera.x, -Camera.y, -Camera.z);
gl.glRotatef    (mRotate.x, 1f, 0f, 0f);
gl.glRotatef    (mRotate.y, 0f, 1f, 0f);
gl.glRotatef    (mRotate.z, 0f, 0f, 1f);
gl.glTranslatef (Camera.x + mOrigin.x, Camera.y + mOrigin.y, Camera.z + mOrigin.z);
```

Comment: I tried both approach but still having same problem its not rotating the from any particular axis..When i do changes only the mRotate.z then it rotate like a slope or parabola..its not what i want. I hope you will look this once again :).I want this https://www.dropbox.com/s/ozt7beo4gz5q293/demo2__A.avi

Comment: I added my complete code at this http://pastebin.com/PGhG1AM3. Please check it and help me. I added one link of dropbox file in above comment which is my client requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The rotation component of the Glulookat seems fine so I dont see any problem there that may cause issues.

First, from the link you provided, it seems to me that you want to rotate about the Y axis although you mentioned the rotation about the Z axis this  can give different results. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ozt7beo4gz5q293/demo2__A.avi

Second, what are the values you are using within the m_Rotate vector? are they in degrees or radians?

third, are you pushing or popping the matrix stack? if so how? or are you feeding your own matrix data into the OpenGL?

also have you made sure to call glLoadIdentity() to set the  view matrix back to identity matrix during your draw calls?

TBH there can be many areas that may cause issue.  To narrow down the possible problem area, do the followings in your draw function;

- stop using GluLookAt.
- remove all push and pop calls,
- firstly make sure to call

  ```
  glLoadIdentity();
  ```
- translate your camera behind the object (in your GLuLookAt this is set to 0,0,10).

  ```
  glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-10.0f);
  ```
- then do simple rotation around the Z axis by;

  ```
  glRotatef(mRotate.z, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
  ```

EDIT: you call onDrawFrame to draw things on the scene as far as I can tell. .  and in this call where you need to do these changes to figure out where your problem is.

instead of this;

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glPushMatrix();

    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER); 

    GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

    //draw_model
    gl.glPushMatrix();

    if(mOrigin != null && mRotate != null) {
        gl.glTranslatef(mOrigin.x, mOrigin.y, mOrigin.z);
        gl.glRotatef(mRotate.x, 1f, 0f, 0f);
        gl.glRotatef(mRotate.y, 0f, 1f, 0f);
        gl.glRotatef(mRotate.z, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    }
    ...
    gl.glPopMatrix();
    gl.glPopMatrix();
  }
```

try something simpler like this.

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW); //making sure OpenGL currently in model view
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                //clear the model view matrix to identity matrix

    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f); //move 10 unit backwards so as if camera moves backwards.
    gl.glRotatef(90.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f)    //rotate 90 degree around the z axis.
    //draw_model
    ...
    //gl.glPopMatrix();
    //gl.glPopMatrix();
  }
```

by doing so your possible problematic area reduced alot. and you can start figuring out the problem. if the above code works, then possible errors reduced alot.
it could be that;

- you setting the matrix mode other then model view somewhere else and not setting it  back  in your draw call,
- you are not clearing the identity matrix in your draw call.
- your origin and rotation values are not correctly done.

BTW: Im not an expert in java but in c++ and  objective c, we can not do 1f to set a value to float. we must use 1.0f otherwise compiler will complain.

Comment: I added the code in the question. Please check it. I hope this will help you and me to find the solution. I hope you will help me :). Please help me by just editing my code

Comment: you have to understand how transformation happens in openGL, just me editing your code is not going to help you achieve that. from the code that I seen you are using the openGL stack to manage your transformation. Have you actually tried what I suggest you to do in the answer? from the updated code I can see that you are not clearing the  view matrix to identity matrix. the answer is written in above. also you have some push and pop calls which doesn't make sense. your GLuLookAt is pretty much pointless if your not looking at a direction. you can simply use glTranslatef instead.

Comment: I tried as you told but now nothing is displayed here. These are changes http://pastebin.com/znbuQE7Z  please check it

Comment: I haven't seen the changes in your draw call they are still same. I edited my answer further to give you some more insight. How are you setting the origin and rotate values , i cant seem to figure it out in your code

Comment: I did same as you told but now object is not appear..`gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER); 
   
      gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW); //making sure OpenGL currently in model view
      gl.glLoadIdentity();                //clear the model view matrix to identity matrix
      gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, 10);` and removed these `//gl.glPopMatrix();
    //gl.glPopMatrix();`

Comment: can you add the part of the code where you call the onDrawFrame method?

Comment: this is overridden method which is called own. It call around 60 times in a seconds

Comment: sorry its the fault in my code. the translation value should have been -10. not 10 so its glTranslationf(0.0f,0.0f, -10.0f) what is happening here is that we moving the object away from the screen. which gives the illusion of the camera beeing positioned from a distance to the object.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36793/discussion-between-nusakan-and-android)